# Interface/class/implement/extend confusion

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to program the Connect Four game in Java, based on some given interfaces.

My problem is that I've got a programming task that includes interfaces that I have got to use, but there are some errors when implementing them. The following interfaces/classes a predetermined:

```
public interface Move {
}

public interface Game<M extends Move> {
...

    pulbic M someMethod(){

    }

...

}

public interface AIPlayer<M extends Move> {
...
}

public class AlphaBetaAlgorithm<G extends Game<M>, M extends Move> implements AIPlayer<M>{
...
}
```

And the now following classes are my own classes I have writen by implementing the upper Interfaces:

```
public class ConnectFourMove implements Move{
...
}

public class ConnectFourGame<ConnectFourMove> implements Game{
...
}
```

The problem is now that inside a method of the "ConnectFourGame" class, i need to use the "AlphaBetaAlgortihm" class, now using "ConnectFourGame" and "ConnectFourMove". So we remember:

```
public class AlphaBetaAlgorithm<G extends Game<M>, M extends Move> implements AIPlayer<M>{
...
}
```

and now what I want to do is:

```
public class ConnectFourGame<ConnectFourMove> implements Game{

...
    public ConnectFourMove someMethod(){

        AlphaBetaAlgorithm alphabeta = new AlphaBetaAlgorithm<ConnectFourGame, ConnectFourMove>();
        ...
   }

...

}
```

I have an error in the class declaration telling me that:

"The type parameter ConnectFourMove is hiding the type ConnectFourMove"

one in the Method declaration, telling me that:

"The return type is incompatible with Game.someMehtod()"

and two in the declaratio of "alphabeta" saying:

"Bound mismatch: The type ConnectFourGame is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter > of the type AlphaBetaAlgorithm"
and
"Bound mismatch: The type ConnectFourMove is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter  of the type AlphaBetaAlgorithm"

What have I done wrong while implementing the interfaces into the classes that causes them not to recognize each other as implementations of the interfaces they usually refer to?

Note: I have imported all packages needed to reach the interfaces that I implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, that's one complex and convoluted layout!  I think the issue is as simple as the way you're defining ConnectFourGame.  Move the ConnectFourMove generic to the Game interface as such:

```
public class ConnectFourGame implements Game<ConnectFourMove>
```

This works because ConnectForGame implements Game, you were implementing Game with no type specified.